# Expresión regular para el formato: "AA-99-99"

Tags: html, html5, blogger

Estoy haciento una web de consulta de matrículas, no se usar el el código "patern" para hacer que se pueda sólo así, creo que se escribe así:

```html
    patern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}"
```

Pero, no sé cómo se pone el guión al en este formato: XX-99-99

Comment: X = Letras mayúsculas | - = - | 9 = Número del 0 al 9

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida, a parte te recomiendo hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas más de como funciona el sitio y también ganes tu primera [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Tu pattern puede ser ^[A-Z]{2}(-\d{2}){2}$ si estas usandolo en una etiqueta html asegurate de usar el atributo title

Comment: Hola, te han votado negativo por que no has agregado el código asociado al problema, al hacer preguntas es importante agregarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Tengo dos soluciones al problema de la expresion regular para tu validacion.

**SOLUCION 1**

1) Usando la expresion regular validas el contenido del campo cuando el usuario pulse el boton de submit.

```html
    <!-- validacion simple -->
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label>PLACA:</label>
        <input type="text" name="" pattern="[A-Z]{2}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}" 
        title="Los valores permitidos son ej: AZ-99-99" placeholder="Ejemplo: AA-99-99" required>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Como lo muestra este ejemplo;

1) La expresion regular usada en `pattern` significa: `[A-Z]{2}`  que los primeros dos caracteres debe ser alfabericos en mayusculas, luego se permite el guion como separador `[-]`, los otros dos caracteres son numericos `[0-9]{2}`, se repite la separacion y finalmente los otros dos caracteres son numericos `[0-9]{2}`.

2) El placeholder indica en el campo un ejemplo de como llenar el campo

3) El `title=""` es el aviso que se mostrara cuando el contenido del campo no corresponda al patron al pulsar el boton de submit y apuntar con el cursor sobre el campo.

**SOLUCION 2**

Exite un recurso llamado mascara el cual crea un formato para el llenado del contenido en el campo facilitando al usuario el llenado de este:

Estos son los link para ampliar la informacion:

https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/inputmask
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PbOEqL

La idea seria combinando la mascara con el pattern para que uno ayude al usuario y el otro valide el contenido al hacer el submit.

Este es el codigo:

```html
    <!-- validacion con jquery -->
    <h3>Validacion con JQuery</h3>
    <form action="" method="POST">
            <label>PLACA Ejemplo: AA-99-99</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="placa"
            title="Los valores permitidos son ej: AZ-99-99"
            pattern="[A-Z]{2}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}"
            >
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
    
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#placa").inputmask({"mask": "[AA]-[99]-[99]"});
       });
    </script>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda...

Comment: Lo mismo con el 2

Comment: Gracias  por el pattern, le puse un intro después de "title='XX-99-99'" y ahí funcionó, porque sin el enter me decía un error de interpretación de /> o >